# How to change cursor on Roll Over event

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a point and click game in AS3 with flash.

I've changed the skin of my cursor by creating a new class "Souris". It's working just fine. Now I'm trying to change the skin of the cursor when it's on an object on the scene.

I've read that the MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER is the good method but I can't figure out how to do it...

I've got my Souris class like that :

```
    public class Souris extends MovieClip
    {
 private var engine:Engine;
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var p:Point = new Point(); 

        public function Souris(stageRef:Stage)
        {
            Mouse.hide(); //make the mouse disappear
            mouseEnabled = false; //don't let our cursor block anything
mouseChildren = false;

            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            x = stageRef.mouseX;
            y = stageRef.mouseY;

            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateMouse, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, updateStack, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,hover);

        }

        private function updateStack(e:Event) : void
        {
            stageRef.addChild(this);
        }
        private function hover(e:MouseEvent):void {
               souris.visible = false;
            }

        private function mouseLeaveHandler(e:Event) : void
        {
            visible = false;
            Mouse.show(); //in case of right click
            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseReturnHandler,    false, 0, true);
        }

        private function mouseReturnHandler(e:Event) : void
        {
            visible = true;
            Mouse.hide(); //in case of right click
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseReturnHandler);
        }

        private function updateMouse(e:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            x = stageRef.mouseX;
            y = stageRef.mouseY;

            e.updateAfterEvent();
        }

    }

}
}
```

In my main class (Engine class) I've got :

```
private var souris:Souris;

public function Engine(){



                        souris = new Souris(stage);
            stage.addChild(souris);

        }
private function startGame(e:Event):void{
....
..
```

I've tried to put in the "Souris" class

```
stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,hover);

private function hover(e:MouseEvent):void {
Engine.souris.visible = false; 
handCursor.visible = true ;
}
```

But it seems wrong...
I don't know what to put in my hover function. (I've got the "handCursor" in my library).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "handCursor" in your library, then you need to assign a class to it, like 'HandCursor'.  I advise that classes start with an uppercase letter.

So your code would need to create a new instance of it then show it, like

```
var handCursor:HandCursor = new HandCursor; handCursor.visible = false;
```

`handCursor.visible = false;` makes it not visible, then to make it visible, you would:

```
handCursor.visible = true;
```

Also, handCursor is a local variable if put in a function, to make it global to use in all functions, you would need to put it at the beginning of your Class.

Also, are you getting any errors?  If so, please share them.

Comment: no errors, but my handCursor doesn't appear when I'm putting my cursor on an item... Do you know why ? I think it's because in my Engine class I'v got souris.visible = true (I've put your code in the "Souris" class)

Comment: No, I think it's the MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER that doesn't work... maybe it's not roll over that I must put...no ?

Comment: @user2421975 glad to hear it, but next time consider the 'trace' statement.